# drawing polygon using leaflet js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to draw a polygon using leaflet js. But the problem Im facing is that when the size increases, it fails to draw the polygon. The same thing is happening when I tried with google maps also. I can draw max of 21 polygon.

Please anyone give me a solution

Answer (score 5):

you can try Leaflet.draw plugin

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/

http://leafletjs.com/2013/02/20/guest-post-draw.html